# different of third type of add role in zend-framework

Tags: php, zend-framework, roles, acl

in zend frame work we can add acl in three type I want to know what is different between them

```
$acl = new Zend_Acl();
// 1st type
$acl -> addRole(new Zend_Acl_Role('someuser'));
// 2nd type
$acl -> add (new Zend_Acl_Role('someuser'));
// 3rd type
$acl -> addRole('someuser');
```

Comment: ZF is open source, so have a look at the [source code](http://framework.zend.com/svn/framework/standard/trunk/library/Zend/Acl.php). If that still doesnt answer your question point out what you do not understand about the source code. Simply asking what's the difference without having looked at the source is extremely lazy.

Answer (score 2):

The first and third are exactly the same. There simply is no difference.
The following happens in the addRole function:

```
if (is_string($role)) {
    $role = new Zend_Acl_Role($role);
}
```

Since `$role` is the given parameter the two are the same.

The second type is deprecated (and used for resources) so using it should be avoided.